# Building multipart form data with multiline Swift strings does not work

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a function that builds multipart form data into a Swift `String`, converts that string to `Data`, then assigns that data to my variable `URLRequest`'s `httpBody` property. When written as a multiline string as such (the content is JPEG `UIImage` data from via `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`):

```
let body = """
--\(formDataBoundary)
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

\(jpegData.base64EncodedString())

--\(formDataBoundary)--
"""
```

It does not work, but assembled by appending multiple times as such:

```
var body = "--\(formDataBoundary)\r\n"
body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"\r\n"
body += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
body += "\(jpegData.base64EncodedString())\r\n\r\n"
body += "--\(formDataBoundary)--"
```

It does. Does anyone have an explanation for as to why? I only comment in and out these two implementations and it's what produces the difference between my `URLSessionDataTask`'s success or failure.

Comment: Is there an error by what you mean that it doesn't work?

Comment: Probably the missing "carriage returns" `\r` in your first version.

Comment: @MartinR is correct. The first version does not include \r characters. You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP and MIME header lines are terminated by a CRLF pair (carriage return + newline, `\r\n`), and that is what you use in

```
var body = "--\(formDataBoundary)\r\n"
// ...
```

Multi-line string literals are separated by a newline character only,
you have to add the required CR characters:

```
let body = """
--\(formDataBoundary)\r
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpeg"\r
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r
\r
\(jpegData.base64EncodedString())\r
\r
--\(formDataBoundary)--\r
"""
```